# Pushing array values by 1

Tags: php

Just wondering if there is a way to push everything in an array by one.
For example:

```
//This will add the first error to array
$error[] = "You must provide a first_name";

//This will add the second error to array
$error[] = "You must provide a last_name";

//This error i want to add at the first index of the array, while pushing the previous two that are already added down a value. But doing it the way i've been doing it just replaces the first index
$error[0] = "This will push the other two errors down one index";
```

Is there anyway to do this without actually getting rid of the first value in the array index.

**FIXED VERSION:**

```
//This will add the first error to array
$error[] = "You must provide a first_name";

//This will add the second error to array
$error[] = "You must provide a last_name";

//This error i want to add at the first index of the array, while pushing the previous two that are already added down a value. But doing it the way i've been doing it just replaces the first index
array_unshift($error, "This will push the other two errors down one index");
```

Thanks to Sharanya Dutta.

Comment: You may consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) one of the following answers.

Comment: yeah sorry i couldn't straight away haha, some issue with a time limit. Done now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in PHP function [`array_unshift`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) will serve your purpose:

```
$error = array();
$error[] = "You must provide a first_name";
$error[] = "You must provide a last_name";
array_unshift($error, "This will push the other two errors down one index");
print_r($error);
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => This will push the other two errors down one index
    [1] => You must provide a first_name
    [2] => You must provide a last_name
)
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/134702)

Answer (score -1):

Crazy dirty hack to start adding from big value. :^ )

```
$error[1000] = "You must provide a first_name";
$error[] = "You must provide a last_name";
$error[0] = "This will push the other two errors down one index";
```